# about ggsave in superheat package

Tags: r

I would like to know how to use ggsave in superheat package.
ggsave does not work......

```
# install devtools
install.packages("devtools")
# use devtools to install superheat
devtools::install_github("rlbarter/superheat")

library(superheat)
superheat(mtcars,
          # scale the matrix columns
          scale = TRUE,
          # change the color
          heat.col.scheme = "red")

g1<-superheat(mtcars,
          # scale the matrix columns
          scale = TRUE,
          # change the color
          heat.col.scheme = "red")

ggsave(file = "heat.tiff", plot =g1, width =6, height = 4)
```

Comment: I don't know `superheat`, but a quick search in the github repo suggests that it doesn't export `ggplot2::ggsave`. Try loading `library(ggplot2)` and try again?

Answer (score 2):

After running the code in the question, I have tried to see wht is the object returned by `superheat`.

It's a list with 7 members. The output of `str(g1)` is too long so check its length first:

```
length(g1)
#[1] 7
```

Now see what is in each of these list members.

```
g1[[1]]
#TableGrob (4 x 2) "layout": 1 grobs
#  z     cells  name                     grob
#1 1 (1-1,2-2) panel gTree[panel-1.gTree.303]

g1[[2]]
#TableGrob (6 x 4) "layout": 4 grobs
#  z     cells   name                     grob
#1 1 (2-2,3-3)  panel gTree[panel-1.gTree.303]
#2 2 (5-5,3-3) layout           gtable[layout]
#3 3 (2-2,2-2) layout           gtable[layout]
#4 4 (3-3,3-3) layout           gtable[layout]
```

The second looks promising, try to save it. (In fact I also saved `g1[[1]]`, it was the heatmap without the axis.)
Note that after some trial and error I have decided to increase the plot's width and height. With the values in the question the axis annotations were not readable.

```
ggplot2::ggsave(file = "heat.tiff", plot = g1[[2]], 
                width = 12, height = 10)
```

[image]

**One final note.** The graph in the picture is a `.png` file, the `.tiff` file displays exactly the same picture.

Comment: or use `ggsave("heat.pdf", g1$plot)`